# String match error "invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'"

Tags: r, string, memory, dplyr, stringr

I have a table that is shaped like this called df (the actual table is 16,263 rows):

```
title             date            brand
big farm house    2022-01-01      A
ranch modern      2022-01-01      A
town house        2022-01-01      C
```

Then I have a table like this called match_list (the actual list is 94,000 rows):

```
words_for_match
farm
town
clown
beach
city
pink
```

And I'm trying to filter the first table to just be rows where the title contains a word in the words_for_match list. So I do this:

```
match_list <- match_list$words_for_match

match_list <- paste(match_list, collapse = "|")

match_list <- sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", match_list)

df %>% 
  filter(grepl(match_list, title))
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Problem while computing `..1 = grepl(match_list, subject)`.
Caused by error in `grepl()`:
! invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'
```

If I filter the table with 94,000 rows to just 1,000 then it runs, so it appears to just be a memory issue. So I'm wondering if there's a less memory-intensive way to do this or if this is an example of needing to look beyond my computer for computation. Advice on either pathway (or other options) is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use: `match_list <-unique( match_list$words_for_match)` and then `df %>% filter(title %in% match_list`?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I'm not looking for exact matches, I'm looking for titles that contain those words, so "town house" would match with "town" and "big farm house" would match with "farm"

Comment: What if you did the following: `ind <- grepl(match_list, dat$title)` and then `dat[ind, ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep titles sequentially, let's say you have 10 titles that match 'farm' you do not need to evaluate those titles with other words.
Here a simple implementation :

```
titles <- c("big farm house", "ranch modern", "town house")
words_for_match <- c("farm", "town", "clown", "beach", "city", "pink")
titles.to.keep <- c()
for(w in words_for_match)
{
    w <- sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", w)
    is.match <- grepl(w, titles)
    titles.to.keep <- c(titles.to.keep, titles[is.match])
    titles <- titles[!is.match]
    print(paste(length(titles), "remaining titles"))
}
titles.to.keep
```

If you have a prior on the frequency of words on match_list, it's better to start with the most frequent ones.

UPDATE

You can also make a mix with your previous strategy to make it faster :

```
gr.size <- 20
gr.words <- split(words_for_match, ceiling(seq_along(words_for_match) / gr.size))
gr.words <- sapply(gr.words, function(words)
{
words <- paste(words, collapse = "|")
sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", words)
})
```

and then iterate on gr.words and not on words_for_match in the first code chunk.

Comment: I mean I'm trying this, but it's been running for almost two hours, so also not an ideal solution lol

Comment: You can make it faster by combining n words together (as you did in your question), I update my answer. The iteration takes time, combining too many words with `|` is memory consuming. The mix of two should be better.